# Scanner Reading

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So, I almost finished creating my minesweeping game but how would I make it so that my scanner, if reads a "string" would reply as a certain sentence. Here is a part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    String cont;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!");

    do {
        a = promptUser(in, "What width of map would you like (3 - 20):", 3, 20);
        b = promptUser(in, "What height of map would you like (3 - 20):", 3, 20);

        char [][] map = new char [b][a];
        eraseMap(map);

        simplePrintMap(map);
        int c = promptUser(in, "row:", 1, a);
        int d = promptUser(in, "column:", 1, b);

        map[c- 1][d - 1] = Config.NO_NEARBY_MINE;

        simplePrintMap(map);

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(y/n)?");

        cont = in.next();
        in.nextLine();
     } while (cont.trim().indexOf("y") == 0);

     System.out.print("Thank you for playing Mine Sweeper!");
}

public static int promptUser(Scanner in, String prompt, int min, int max) {

    int userInput;

    System.out.println(prompt);
    userInput = in.nextInt();

    while (userInput < min || userInput > max){
        System.out.println("Expected a number from " + min + " to " + max + ".");
         userInput = in.nextInt();
     }

    return userInput;
}
```

So in my method of promptUser, it would ask for a int value of the width and height of the game map. However, if I wanted it to reply "Expected a number...." if I wrote a string instead of a int, how would I change it as?

Comment: please format your code correctly, it is pretty hard to read as is.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to check if your userInput contains only digits using regex pattern match.

```
   String userInput = in.nextLine();
   if(userInput.matches("\\d+"))
   { 
       //use this as your input, it is an int (clearing up your confusion)
       int coOrd = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
   }
   else
   {
      //code block if false
   }
```

Comment: This will work, if you use nextLine() instead of nextInt() to read the user input.

Comment: Just wondering, is there another method that doesnt use parse?

Comment: Personally wouldn't use anything other than parseInt() for parsing a string argument into an Integer Object. You will end up with an Int to use much like you would using the nextInt() method. Reason I wouldn't use nextInt() etc. is because the user input "1 test" to nextInt() is valid and returns the value of 1.